# How to get the name of the currently executing trigger and the name of the table it is attached to, in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008

I have a common line of T-SQL to put into many triggers. I want to be able to use the name of the currently executing trigger and the table name that the trigger is attached to.

I could hard code this for each trigger but that is a lot of work that I'd like to avoid, so is there some inbuilt functionality that will give me what I want?

Whilst waiting for an answer, I have discovered half of my question:

```
 OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
```

will give me the trigger name

Just need to get the table name now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK found it myself:

```
SELECT name tablename, OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) triggername
FROM sys.objects
WHERE object_id = (SELECT parent_object_id
                   FROM sys.objects
                   WHERE NAME = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID))
```